# Show Success message is not Working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: "POST",
     url:'/saveLayout',          
     data: {id : layoutId, section :  arrSection},
     success: function(response){  
               $('#successMsg').addClass("errorBox");
               document.getElementById('successMsg').innerHTML="Your data has been successfully          saved.";
              }
    });
```

Show success message in ajax success function is not working in second time in Crome.
The success message works at first time. But its not working after that.

Comment: Go to questions you've asked before and select an answer for them. (There should be a hollowed-out check mark next to each answer.)

Comment: Done. Am new to this that's why.... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is reusing the same HTML block to display the success message, so the second message  will simply replace the first. If you want it to display two success messages at the same time, then you will need to append the message. Is that the problem?

Here is an example of appending the message:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'/saveLayout',
    data: {
        id : layoutId,
        section : arrSection
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $("#successMsg").addClass("errorBox").append("Your data has been successfully saved.");
    }
});
```

Comment: In Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+i to bring up the dev tools and click on the Console tab. Reload your page and see if it is reporting any Javascript errors when it runs your code.

Comment: Odd. Here is a simplified example that works in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/nFKvp/

Comment: First time this ajax function is work... but after that without page reload this success message is not shown.

Comment: If the page is reloading, then there is most likely a problem with the code that is triggering the ajax call and not the code snippet that you posted in your question. You should post more of your code or even better, a jsfiddle link to show your code in action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9888/discussion-between-anupama-and-nick-c)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to remove the errorbox class before add.

```
$('#successMsg').removeClass("errorBox"); 
$('#successMsg').addClass("errorBox");
```

Comment: Yes, I just removed this in on change function(Dropdown). After that again click the save button... that time its not work.. In Firefox, It works perfectly.

Comment: How do you want it to work? Appending it for each success ajax?

Comment: may be this problem due to cached. Anupama, is ur problm resolved by replaced this answer?

Comment: When i call this ajax function I need to display this message.. I don't need to apped this